Merge replication how to apply latest subscriber changes
I use merge push replication, everything works. I have a publisher server and two subscribers, if both subscribers change the same value in a row in the table, I get a conflict, the one who changed the value first wins.
I want it to work like this: the one who made the last changes wins, how do I set this up?
For example, one subscriber changes the name column in the user table, another does the same, and as a result I receive changes from the very first subscriber, how can I make it so that the changes from the one who made them most recently are applied?

I'm not expert, but perhaps https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/replication/merge/advanced-merge-replication-conflict-com-based-resolvers?view=sql-server-ver16  Microsoft SQL Server DATETIME (Later Wins) Conflict Resolver might be of interest?

You are right, thank you, this is the answer.
